# Type 'void | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' when trying to render string

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom hook which returns an array of objects(navMenuOptions) and a function which can return a specific navMenuOption based on a string.

```
export const useNavMenuOptions = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()

  const profile = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'profile.navMenu.profile' })
  const addresses = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'profile.navMenu.addresses' })
  const myOrders = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'profile.navMenu.myOrders' })

  const navMenuOptions: NavMenuOption[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      label: profile,
      icon: BiUser,
      url: '/account/profile',
    },

    {
      id: 1,
      label: addresses,
      icon: BiHomeAlt,
      url: '/account/address',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: myOrders,
      icon: BsBoxSeam,
      url: '/account/my-orders',
    },
  ]

  const findSelectedOption = (url: string) => {
    const selectedOption: NavMenuOption | undefined = navMenuOptions.find(
      (option) => option.url === url
    )
    if (selectedOption?.label) {
      return selectedOption?.label
    }
    return -1
  }

  return { navMenuOptions, findSelectedOption }
}
```

I am then trying to use the `findSelectedOption()` function in a component and render the string it returns

```
export const NavMenuMobile: React.FC<NavMenuProps> = ({
  navMenuOptions,
  changeMenuOption,
  currentOption,
  findSelectedOption,
}) => {
  const selectedOption = useMemo(() => {
    return findSelectedOption?.(currentOption)
  }, [currentOption])

  console.log('selected option =>', selectedOption)

  return (
    <Box p={4} borderBottomWidth="2px" borderBottomColor="shading.200">
      {selectedOption}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

`selectedOption` is returning the correct string but I have a TS lint error:

**Type 'void | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.**

what is the fix here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native really doesn't like `undefined` being rendered. Try `null` instead.

```
const selectedOption = useMemo(() => {
  return findSelectedOption?.(currentOption) ?? null
}, [currentOption])
```

Or:

```
{selectedOption ?? null}
```